# Creating Bucket using LearnBoost/Knox

Tags: node.js

working on project where I have to use Amazon S3 services and thus using LearnBoost/knox...want to know how to create a bucket using the knox client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to this question, and found this unanswered.  I ended up with the following solution:

https://gist.github.com/1508111