# How can i create bucket with knox on S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knox)

iwanna create bucket with knox but dont find it . Anyone can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Bucket using LearnBoost/Knox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568261/creating-bucket-using-learnboost-knox)

Comment: yes i saw it but not work for me.They say dynAws do it . But i cant find what is dynAws

Comment: $bucket = 'your-bucket-id'; 
Config::set('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket', $bucket); 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-create-aws-s3-buckets-dynamic-buckets?page=0

Comment: its for amazon web service(AWS SDK). we use personal s3 on server. so not possible use it